# Setting caret position where caret has not been in JTextArea

Tags: java, swing, jtextarea, keylistener, caret

Is there anyway I can set the caret position in my JTextArea where the caret position has not been before?  I would like to add text to my JTextArea using KeyListener on the KeyEvent.VK_ENTER, and then set the caret position one line underneath where I add the text to the JTextArea.

Cheers,

Taylor

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> using KeyListener on the KeyEvent.VK_ENTER

Don't use a KeyListener. Swing was designed to be used with Key Bindings. Read the section from the Swing tutorial on [How to Use Key Bindings](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/keybinding.html) for more information.

> set the caret position one line underneath where I add the text to the JTextArea.

Make sure you append a "\n" to the text area when you add the text. Then you can just use:

```
textArea.setCaretPosition( textArea.getDocument().getLength() );
```

Answer (score 1):

- I strongly urge you to not use a KeyListener as the use of low-level listeners is discouraged and can make your code harder to upgrade and modify.
- What is your ultimate goal as there may be a better way.
- To add a new line, simply do that: add a new line to the JTextArea via `textArea.append("\n");`
- Then advance the cursor to the end of the JTextArea via `setCaretPosition(...)`

Comment: My ultimate goal is to get a string back from matlab server and append it to my JTextArea in a GUI that I have created.  I use key listener VK_ENTER to send the text to the matlab server.  Do you have a suggestion for an alternate route than the key listener?

Comment: @TaylorFireman: yes, either Key Bindings, a DocumentListener or a DocumentFilter depending on the situation.